# How can I reuse information stored in one variable in a function in another function without prompting the user again?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to create a mini-program where if someone clicks on a button, they are asked to enter their name. Then if they double click the second button, they are alerted their name (based on the information entered through the first button.

The first button works fine, but I am not sure why double clicking the second button results in the alert `Your name is undefined`. I understand that `firstName` is a local variable inside the function `firstButtonClick()`, but is there a way for me to reuse this information in `secondButtonClick()` without prompting the user again for their name? See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<button id="namebutton" type="submit">Click me to store your name</button>

<br>
<br>
<hr>
<br>

<button id="butt" type="submit">Double click me to return your name</button>

<script>

    var firstName;

    /* function where you are asked to enter your name and 
    alerted some text */
function firstButtonClick() {

    var firstName = prompt("Enter your first name", '');
    alert("Thank you for entering your name. Please click the button below!");

}

 /* function where you are alerted with your name based on what 
 info you entered before*/
function secondButtonClick() {

    var firstName;
alert("Your name is " + firstName);

}

/* if click on first button, run function firstButtonClick() */
document.getElementById("namebutton").onclick=function() {
    firstButtonClick();

}

/* if click on second button, run function secondButtonClick() */
document.getElementById("butt").ondblclick=function() {
    secondButtonClick();

}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: `var firstName = prompt` <-- remove the `var`

Comment: `var firstName;` <--- makes no sense in the secondButtonClick method, delete it

Comment: Looks like you need to learn about scope of variables. when you use var inside of a block, you no longer have access to the var outside of the block.

Comment: I have added more explanation to your answers below. Kindly refer it and accept the answer if you find it most useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var firstName = undefined;

/* function where you are asked to enter your name and alerted some text */
function firstButtonClick() {
    firstName = prompt("Enter your first name", '');
    alert("Thank you for entering your name. Please click the button below!");
}

 /* function where you are alerted with your name based on what info you entered before*/
function secondButtonClick() {
    alert("Your name is " + firstName);
}
```

This way the firstName variable is neatly declared outside of your functions and you can set / get that variable from each.

Comment: Thanks so much! That ended up working :) - just to clarify, does making the variable firstName undefined work to kind of make it 'open' to be being defined? Also, I noticed that if I technically assign any string to the firstName variable then it ends up getting overrided when I click on the second button anyway. Would it be bad practice to let var firstName = "first_name" and then use the rest of your code (rather than undefined)?

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding the error in your code

First of all, the function you have created to receive input creates unexpected results.

```
function firstButtonClick() {

    var firstName = prompt("Enter your first name", '');
    alert("Thank you for entering your name. Please click the button below!");

}
```

Here you are re-declaring the `firstName` once again inside of the function.
This creates a new variable `firstName` that has access only to `firstButtonClick`. Read more about [variable scope here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Second, when analyzing the output there can be several different reasons for a variable returning `undefined`. Read more [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/7-tips-to-handle-undefined-in-javascript/). In your case the error occurs in this function.

```
function secondButtonClick() {
    var firstName;
    alert("Your name is " + firstName);
}
```

You are only re-declaring the variable `firstName` inside `secondButtonClick()` function without initializing it with a value. When you declare a variable by having a `var` a statement in a block, but haven't yet assigned a value to it, it is `undefined`. So when you alert the variables it simply outputs `undefined` instead of expected value.

### Solution

Define `firstName` in the global level (Outside of any function) and assign it to an empty string like below.

```
var firstName = ""
```

This makes your code more readable and predictable. Read more about [JavaScript best practices here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp)

Remove `var` keyword before the `firstName` inside the `firstButtonClick` function to prevent re-declaring and limiting the scope of the variable. Then simply alert the `firstName` in the `secondButtonClick()` function.

Also I would like to suggest you to learn [ES6 standards](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)  to make your code more robust and clean

Finally the corrected functions look like below.

```
var firstName;

function firstButtonClick() {
        firstName = prompt("Enter your first name", '');
        alert("Thank you for entering your name. Please click the button below!");
}
      
function secondButtonClick() {
        alert("Your name is " + firstName);
}
```

Refer this corrected snippet for completed code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <button id="namebutton" type="submit">
  Click me to store your name
  </button>
  
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  
  <button id="butt" type="submit">
    Double click me to return your name
  </button>

<script>
  var firstName;
  
  function firstButtonClick() {
    firstName = prompt("Enter your first name", '');
    alert("Thank you for entering your name. Please click the button below!");
  }
  
  function secondButtonClick() {
    alert("Your name is " + firstName);
  }

  document.getElementById("namebutton").onclick = function(){
    firstButtonClick();
  }

  document.getElementById("butt").ondblclick = function() {
    secondButtonClick();
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have declared the variable `firstName` twice by putting `var` in front of both usages of the variable.